# Hack your machine domain lookup capability

Tags: networking, domain-name-system

I want to put some entry in some file such as

www.google.com 127.0.0.1

So that whenever a linux user types the domain name www.google.com on his browser then the website hosted on the localhost comes. Can somebody tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is answer?

linux:
echo ' 127.0.0.1 www.google.com' >> /etc/hosts

windows:

put line into windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: if i am using proxy server to access my internet then this trick doesnot works since it redirects all traffic to proxy server. Can you please tell me how to do in that scenario.

Comment: ya thanks a lot .. i got that also .. what i did that in the browser i used the "no proxy for" option and put there www.google.com. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The file you're after is `/etc/hosts`